# How to disabled Bluetooth features?

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth

I'm trying make the master send packets of specified type(such as DH1/2DH-5/3DH-1...) in paring mode,but due to `CQDDR`,the slave will send LMP_PREFERRED_RATE to change packet type for retaining its throughput. So I want to disabled the `CQDDR` for making the master keep sending `DH5` or `2DH-5`... How to solve this problem?

[image]

I've tried to send `cmd(hcitool cmd 0x01 0x000f 0x0B 0x00 0x06 0xF3)` in a for loop, but it didn't work.